# How do I modify the GRUB boot menu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, grub

I have dual boot **Windows 8.1** and **Ubuntu 14.04**.  When Ubuntu installed GRUB, it created two entries for Windows 8.1, one for /dev/sda1 and one for /dev/sda2.

How do I change the boot menu entries to remove the redundant choice?  Also, how do I extend the boot menu delay time?

Comment: Are the entries identical?  Often, you will see entries for each partition (recovery partition, main Windows partition, sometimes it will even setup GRUB so you can boot on other partitions).  They will appear as sdax where "x" is a different number for each partition.

Comment: both the entries are on different partition.It is showing `Windows 8 (loader) on dev/sda1`and `Windows 8 (loader) on dev/sda2`.

Comment: One is probably the hidden system partition. See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280026/how-do-i-hide-an-entry-from-grub

Answer (score 0):

The **GRUB** can be modified using an GUI application called the ***GRUB CUSTOMIZER*** .

To install **GRUB CUSTOMIZER** follow the below steps-

- Open Terminal
- Type the following command:
  **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer** .This PPA contains the latest release of Grub Customizer and adds a repository for Grub Customizer .
- Next update your repositories by typing :**sudo apt-get update** , since a new repository has been added.
- Next download the grub-customizer by typing : **sudo apt-get install grub-customizer**.